# Find Mutations Frequencies by Cancer Type

Tags: genetics, cancer, dna-sequencing

Is there somewhere that has mutation frequencies by cancer type? So if I were looking at CML, AML, or even more generally at something like leukemia. Is there some database that would contain mutation frequencies? So that I could find that in leukemia 50% of cancers contained a T100G mutation.

I have looked through COSMIC but haven't had much luck.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? There is a paper which looked at the mutation frequencies of different cancers, I can look it up in my database if you want.

Comment: @Chris If that much info is in a paper that would certainly work. I figure this sort of thing would be in a hosted database though.

Comment: Try http://dcc.icgc.org

Answer (score 2):

There is one paper called "Mutational heterogeneity in cancer and the search for new cancer-associated genes" from the "The cancer genome atlas" which should be interesting for you. This project aims to map the mutations occurring in different cancers, one of the results is this figure (from reference 1):

[image]

The project itself has numerous data on the different cancers available on the project website, which can be found in reference 2.

References:

1. [Mutational heterogeneity in cancer and the search for new
   cancer-associated genes](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v499/n7457/full/nature12213.html)
2. [The cancer genome atlas project website](http://cancergenome.nih.gov/)

Comment: Thanks I actually remember this paper, I have it in my ref manager as well. I'll go back and look at it and check those sites to see if I can find what I need.